Entity Framework Save data that exceeds 50kb issue
Details:

Entity Framework 6.4.4, using Owin and OData. (not sure if that helps with explaining).
Asp.net Mvc project, using .net framework 4.7.2 (limitation of legacy projects that cannot be updated at this time).

Situation:
In our application there is a rich text editor that the users can use to create content for another application. In the rich text editor it is possible (and needs to continue to be possible) to add images. Everything is outputted as html with imbedded css, where the images appear as base64 strings in the . This is then sent to the server to save via EFContext.SaveChanges();
If the combined size of the package is more than 50KB of data, it throws an exception saying "RequestEntityTooLarge".
We have a method that can Shrink the images, but it destroys the image quality drastically if the image was a few MB, and then got crunched down to a < 50KB .jpg size.
The customers dont like it, so I must find a way to fix it.
The IIS transaction logs have no records of these transactions ever being sent. So the error happens before the request leaves the application.
We tried:
I was aware of the fact that base64 strings are very long, so I created an algorithm, that plucks out the base64 strings and replaces them with placeholders and an Id for a DB table row, where the image will be store separately. And then on edit or display, you regex the html and replace the placeholders with the images. works perfectly, except that the DB simply doesn't accept any files / data above 50 kb.
I asked Copilot to find ways to remedy the situation and it suggests the stuff that every site on the internet always say:
Web.config
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" requestLengthDiskThreshold="2147483647" maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>

We also tried setting the uploadReadAheadSize but the project wont run with this in the web.config, unless you change the applicationHost.config file's <section name="serverRuntime" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />. Based on a few articles I read about this, they changed it, so it must be done on server side. I could be wrong.
Tried to edit the ApplicationHost.config file doing the following changes:
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="51200" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <serverRuntime uploadReadAheadSize="52428800" />
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="52428800" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>


None of it worked. We tried it both on a test server, with remote desktop access, where we looked into iis settings and all that stuff. But as I said, the IIS never received any of the requests related to this issue.
I have exhausted the AI to find a solution for this, google isn't helpful. I need human eyes to look into my specific situation, ask me questions, and maybe we can figure it out together.

50 KB, really?

The "uploadReadAheadSize" on the application host config file should cover it. To ensure the setting is correct, did you adjust it using IIS's application configuration UI?

@GertArnold yes, its absurdly outdated with such a low transfer limit. But alas.

@StevePy My Manager did the "uploadReadAheadSize" and other settings on our test server's iis manager settings. And I attempted to fix it locally for my localhost, via applicationHost.config.

Bumping this up, since there still is no answers
